# Qt one project knows the other ones classes

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, directory-structure

Have tried to "link" two projects together. So one project knows the other ones classes. One project is the program, the other project is a test program for the first one. So i want the test program to have access to the other ones classes so i can test them.

Both projects are sub projects.
They are placed under header project, there folders are beside each other.

Have tried many different ways but with no result.

Head.pro

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    MT \
    Test
```

MT.pri same folder as the program.

```
INCLUDEPATH  += $$PWD
SOURCES      += $$PWD/parser.cpp
HEADERS      += $$PWD/parser.h
```

MT.pro

```
QT       += core bluetooth gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MT
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG += mobility

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
    t.cpp \
    parser.cpp \
    devicediscovery.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
     parser.h \
     devicediscovery.h \
     t.h \
     typedefs.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


MOBILITY =

INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
    MT.pri
```

Test.pro

```
include(../MT/MT.pri)
QT       += widgets testlib core bluetooth gui

TARGET = tst_testmttest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

HEADERS += parser.h
SOURCES += tst_testmttest.cpp / parser.cpp
DEFINES += SRCDIR=\\\"$$PWD/\\\"
```

Comment: This seems like a question regarding include path configuration of your compiler. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to use .pri file, also tried to include path in the other projects pro file. Are a noob at this such of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in Test Project:

```
include(Path/to/OtherProject/file.pri)
```

Use in Other project

```
QT       += xml
INCLUDEPATH  += $$PWD
SOURCES      += $$PWD/parser.cpp
HEADERS      += $$PWD/parser.h
```

works fine

Comment: ``xml`` is just for example

Comment: The last one is it for the .pri file or the .pro file?

Comment: Maybe help, but got symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 when i created a object in Test from a class in MT.

Comment: Just needed to do the last part for every custom classes that where connected to the class i wanted to test. Thx!